# HttpClient 5 - how to release connection?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

HttpClient 5 - how to release connection?
I'm using HttpClient 5 to write spider. The response is 'org.apache.hc.client5.http.async.methods.SimpleHttpResponse' but I couldn't find any method to release connection.

DO NOT hope to use CloseableHttpAsyncClient.close() because this is a spider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `HttpAsyncClient` connections get released automatically.